# rails find model without loading relevant associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, associations, destroy

My rails application has two models, gallery and photo.  Galleries have many photos and photos belong to one gallery.

When I delete a photo, I noticed that rails also loads the gallery - which I do not need.  It is an added database query.

When I `find` the photo to delete, I use `@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])`.  This loads the association.

I know that there is `@photo = Photo.find(params[:id], :include => :gallery)`, which tells it to load the gallery.  What is the opposite of this?  I tried the following:

```
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id], :include => [])
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id], :include => nil)
```

I also tried to select only the fields that I need in order to delete the photo, but I need the `gallery_id` in order to delete the actual file because the path of the file is based off the gallery.  This just ends up loading the gallery too.

Edit:
My `Photo` model looks like this:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery

    mount_uploader :file, PhotoUploader
end
```

`mount_uploader` is from [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).  I have an uploader with the following code in it:

```
def store_dir_base
    "galleries/#{model.gallery.id}/"
end
```

Could it be the culprit?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not the same behavior I see. Maybe there is something in your model(s) that forces the association to load?

Comment: adding to what zetetic says; are you sure you aren't missing more code then what you are posting?  you say you need to gallery_id to delete the file, so why would you NOT want the gallery loaded too? Is it part of your routes?

Comment: and I answered my own question - that was it - the `store_dir_base` code.  I changed `"galleries/#{model.gallery.id}/"` to `"galleries/#{model.gallery_id}/"` to access the column instead of the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was happening was because of my `uploader` code that I used for carrierwave.

This code was accessing the gallery model, when all I needed to access was the id:

```
def store_dir_base
    "galleries/#{model.gallery.id}/"
end
```

All I had to do was change it to:

```
def store_dir_base
    "galleries/#{model.gallery_id}/"
end
```

This made it so I was accessing the `photo` model column `gallery_id` instead of the `gallery` model.